# Pasar parametro de consulta a base de datos a controlador

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Tengo un controlador, una vista y un modelo, a parte de la carpeta destinada a crear las rutas, lo que quiero es pasar lo que recojo en la consulta a la base de datos ($users) al controlador y que este lo pase a la vista. Informaros de que si hago la consulta en el controlador todo funciona perfecto, por lo que creo que el fallo esta unicamente en como paso el parametro al controlador, ya que este o no llega o llega vacio tras muchos intentos y rato dandole vueltas, os dejo el codigo a continuacion:

web.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

use App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\userController;
use App\Models\usersCons;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');

Route::get('users', [userController::class, 'listarUsers']);
```

usersCons.php:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

    class usersCons extends User{

        public function buscarUsers(){

            $users = DB::table('users')->get();

            return $users;

        }

    }

?>
```

userController:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Models\usersCons;

    class userController extends Controller{

        public function listarUsers(){

            // $users = usersCons::select('select * from users');
            $users_model = new usersCons;
            $users = $users_model->buscarUsers();

            return view('layouts\usersView')->with('users', $users);

        }
    }

?>

?>
```

usersView.blade.php:

```
@foreach ( $users as $user)

    <h4>{{$user->id}}. {{ $user->name }} </h4>
    <br>

@endforeach
```

Comment: La verdad es que es difícil de entender lo que tienes. Es decir, nunca le pasas parámetros a tu vista, mira la documentación de [cómo pasar datos a las vistas blade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views), por eso te está dando error

Comment: @gaidyjg es que le quiero pasar loa datos de la consulta al controlador, y de ahi a la vista, que eso si lo hace bien, lo que pasa es que nunca llegan al controlador, lo que digo es que no se como pasarlos al controlador, ya se que no le estoy pasando nada ahora mismo

Comment: Es que si estás [haciendo un scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes), lo estás haciendo mal también porque, según entiendo, en tu controlador nunca llamas al método que está en tu DB. Te recomendaría acomodaras mejor tu pregunta porque no se entiende mucho en realidad.

Comment: @gaidyjg perdona, el controller estaba mal copiado, ahora hice unas modificaciones y funciona pero queria saber si hay una forma mas 'estilo laravel' en vez de hacerlo igual que en php puro aunque asi funcione

Answer (score 1):

La consulta a la BD la podrías hacer con eloquent(laravel) de la siguiente forma.
Directamente al modelo User, y devolver a la vista con compact.

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Models\User;

    class userController extends Controller{

        public function listarUsers(){

            $users = User::all();

            return view('layouts\usersView', compact('users'));

        }
    }

?>
```